# На конце получаемой строки из объекта NULL

Tags: php, json

Получаю данные от вк

```
object(stdClass)#21 (1) { 
["response"]=> 
    object(stdClass)#2 (2) { 
        ["count"]=> int(3) 
        ["items"]=> 
            array(3) { 
                [0]=> 
                    object(stdClass)#1 (11) {
                        ["id"]=> int(57) 
                        ["from_id"]=> int(-155) 
                        ["owner_id"]=> int(-155) 
                        ["date"]=> int(1512904404) 
                        ["marked_as_ads"]=> int(0) 
                        ["post_type"]=> string(4) "post" 
                        ["text"]=> string(3) "test" 
                        ["attachments"]=> 
                            array(1) { 
                                [0]=> 
                                    object(stdClass)#3 (2) { 
                                        ["type"]=> string(4) "poll" 
                                        ["poll"]=> 
                                            object(stdClass)#4 (8) { 
                                                ["id"]=> int(280) 
                                                ["owner_id"]=> int(-155) 
                                                ["created"]=> int(1512904404) 
                                                ["question"]=> string(3) "test" 
                                                ["votes"]=> int(1) 
                                                ["answer_id"]=> int(0) 
                                                ["answers"]=> 
                                                    array(1) { 
                                                        [0]=> 
                                                            object(stdClass)#5 (4) { 
                                                                ["id"]=> int(944428753) 
                                                                ["text"]=> string(2) "var1"
```

Пытаюсь достать ответ

```
echo (string)$wall->response->items[0]->attachments[0]->poll->answers[0]->text
//result: var1NULL
```

Как этого избежать? Почему NULL? Что не так?

Comment: Но ведь `var1` у вас тоже выводится? подозреваю, что у вас в цикле какая-то обработка ведется - скорее всего, совершается лишняя итерация в конце. Либо этот NULL выводится вообще где-то дальше.

Comment: Правильно, добавьте . PHP_EOL в конце echo чтобы следующий echo был с новой строки для понимания.